# Trying to download Eclipse IDE brings me to 400 Error Page

Tags: java, eclipse, download

***The Issue***

I have tried to download Eclipse IDE from this link: http://eclipse.bluemix.net/packages/2018-12/?INSTALLER-WIN64

which I got to from here: 
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2018-12/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe

When I open the exe that it downloads, my browser will open up to this link:
https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/?vm=1_1_7_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png

Which for me resolves to a 400 bad Request Error, which looks like this: 
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i6eL.png)

---

***My attempted fixes***

I have tried clearing my cookies and history of the site, I have also tried to run as adminstrator. I have also asked two other friends to see if they got the same error. One does get the error but the other one is able to run the download with no problem.

---

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Try to download the original Eclipse Installer (at the top) instead of a sponsored version from a member. Alternatively, you can directly download an IDE package as ZIP: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ Make also sure Java 8 or higher is installed.

Comment: Theres an option on your second URL to [>> Select Another Mirror](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2018-12/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe). You should try another mirror/source for the download in case there is an issue with the default it chose for you.

Comment: @howlger After I downloaded the zip version I found out that I had the 32 bit version of Java instead of 64 bit. After switching everything worked, thank you!